# Ошибка "TypeError: can't concat str to bytes" при отправке данных на socket

Tags: python

Имеется контроллер, на который нужно удалённо подать определённое количество байтов. Решил реализовать это с помощью сокетов в python.

Набросал вот такой код:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('192.168.1.205', 2000))
sock.send(b'3C53544152543E090000000456000000'+'386'+'00003C454E443E')
sock.close()
```

но python выдаёт ошибку:

> ```
> sock.send(b'3C53544152543E090000000456000000'+'386'+'00003C454E443E')
> TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
> ```

Как исправить эту ошибку? (пробовал исправить через ( `bytes()`, `encoding()`) 
или может кто-нибудь подскажет другой метод решения данной задачи)).

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка связана с тем, что вы пытаетесь к байтовой строке прикрепить (concat - конкатенация - сцепление строк) две обычных строки:

```
b'3C53544152543E090000000456000000'+'386'+'00003C454E443E'
```

Чтобы просто убрать ошибку нужно добавить префкис `b` к двум другим строкам:

```
b'3C53544152543E090000000456000000'+b'386'+b'00003C454E443E'
```

Но у меня есть подозрение, что вам нужна не последовательность байт `b'3C53544152543E...'`, а последовательность вида `b'\x3C\x53\x54\x41\x52\x54\x3E...'`.

Чтобы вручную не добавлять `\x` в коде перед каждой парой шестнадцатеричных цифр, можно воспользоваться функцией [**binascii.unhexlify**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify). Пример:

```
>>> import binascii

>>> binascii.unhexlify('3C53544152543E090000000456000000')
b'<START>\t\x00\x00\x00\x04V\x00\x00\x00'
```

В вашем коде отправка данных будет выглядеть так:

```
from binascii import unhexlify as unhex

...

sock.send(unhex('3C53544152543E090000000456000000')+b'386'+unhex('00003C454E443E'))
```